# Prevent Systemd Requires from executing on restart

Tags: systemd

I have an application I'd like to compile once on boot and if it succeeds, run it. I have two services: `compile-app` and `run-app`. When I set it up using `Requires` it works but whenever I do `systemctl restart run-app` it also re-runs `compile-app`, which I don't want.

How can I restructure my services to not run `compile-app` when I manually restart `run-app`?

```
# compile-app.service

[Unit]
Description=compile app
After=network-online.target syslog.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=some command
RemainAfterExit=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and

```
# run-app.service

[Unit]
Description=run app
After=network-online.target syslog.target
Wants=network-online.target
Requires=compile-app.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=some command

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

EOF
```

Is what I have now.

Answer (score 1):

`RemainAfterExit=true` should already do the trick. Are you sure that `compile-app.service` really gets stopped/restarted when you stop/restart the other unit?

You should also add `compile-app.service` to the `After` of `run-app.service`. The way it is right now, there's no ordering relation between the two services, so they will be started in parallel. Remember that `Wants/Requires/Conflicts` doesn't imply any ordering and similarly, `Before/After` doesn't imply any dependency.

Comment: A good way to troubleshoot this is looking at `systemctl status compile-app.service`, if it's not in status `started` then it will be started again when `run-app` restarts. But I definitely agree that `RemainAfterExit=true` should get the correct behavior.